# Java FilePath Android

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that I am trying to get a file path for a SAX parser. I have the following structure:

```
assets:(Where my xml file is)
src(same level as assets)
   com
       msi
          androidrss(The calling java file is in here)
```

I tried several variations of this:

```
InputSource is = new InputSource("file://../../../../assets/Rss.xml");
```

But I always get a `FNF Exception`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use File APIs to get at data in the assets directory when you're running from your APK. You have to use the [Android - AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) class. You get an instance of the AssetManager class from the Context object. See [Context object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Answer (score 1):

Place the xml at `/res/raw` and open it with:

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xmlName);
```

Comment: I think that should be `xmlResourceId` instead of `xmlName`.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the answer by @typo.pl:

```
InputStream in = getContext().getAssets().open("Rss.xml");
// test that in is not null
try {
    // set up your SAX parser and handler
    parser.parse(in, handler);
} finally {
    try { in.close(); }
    catch (IOException ignored) {}
}
```